# Arrays inside Arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to make multiple arrays by accessing the parent array.  for eg. 
how do make this array?

Here, in this code, the following data is inputted by the user and the code will simply print the arrays i.e. 
2->total size of the parent array (it will tell the compiler that user will enter two arrays as input) 
6->size of the first child array and so on.

---

```
2
6
5 1 3 4 18 56
8
8 7 3 1 34 72 89 11
```

and all of them are user-input even the size of the array.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) { 
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   int sarr[] = new int[30];
   int arr[] =  new int[30];
   int n =sc.nextInt();
   for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
   { sarr[i] = sc.nextInt();
     for (int j=0;j<=sarr[i];j++)
     { 
      arr[j]=sc.nextInt();
     }
   }
   for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
   { 
     for (int j=0;j<=sarr[i];j++)
     { 
        System.out.println(arr[i]);
     }
     System.out.println();
   }
```

Comment: Please provide code (mimimum working and runnable snippet) as well as desired output

Comment: Hey, please check it.. I changed it.

Comment: Also, can anyone tell me how to access a particular element of the array? Like applying a sort operation on each of the array?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a multidimensional array in java, you should use this syntax:

```
int n = ...; 
int array[][] = new int[n][n];
```

For example:

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int arr[][] = new int[n][n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                System.out.println(arr[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Some final notes:

- You should close the stream when you are done with it
- You don't "tell the compiler" since the compiler is not executed at runtime. You mean the JVM, in any case.

Comment: I don't suppose this is this solution...please try to at least read the problem..it's not about 2D array but 2D array inside an array..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for how you can build a 2D array with rows of different sizes. Each array is created after we have asked for its size

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Number of arrays");
String str1 = sc.nextLine();
int numberOfArrays = Integer.valueOf(str1);

int[][] array = new int[numberOfArrays][];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfArrays; i++) {
        System.out.println("Size of array");
        String str2 = sc.nextLine();
        int size = Integer.valueOf(str2);
        int[] row = new int[size];
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            System.out.println("Value:");
            String str3 = sc.nextLine();
            int value = Integer.valueOf(str3);
            row[j] = value;
        }
        array[i] = row;        
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

Here is a version that allows all numbers in the array to be entered on a single line. Note that there is no error handling here checking the number of values given vs expected etc.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfArrays; i++) {
    System.out.println("Size of array");
    String str2 = sc.nextLine();
    int size = Integer.valueOf(str2);
    int[] row = new int[size];
    System.out.println("Values:");
    String str3 = sc.nextLine();
    String[] numbers = str3.split("\\s");
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        row[j] = Integer.valueOf(numbers[j]);
    }
    array[i] = row;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell me why you used string to take input instead of taking directly integer value?

Comment: To avoid the the issue where only the int value is read but not the end-of-line (enter/return) character is read which might cause an issue the next time the scanner is read.

Comment: Sorry man, your code isn't working. I don't understand why! it showing this error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0 2 1 2 0" at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

Comment: It was some time since I wrote this but it looks like I expect one number at a time to be entered. If you want to read a line of multiple numbers change the last scanner read to `nextInt` instead

Comment: @Shinichi I do not get an exception when I run my code and enter one value per line

Comment: @Shinichi I added an alternative solution for the loop part